# Adding author, version etc. information from code

Tags: c++, winapi

For example, I made some program. Can I fill author, version etc. information(in File Property Window) for my .exe file from code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to complete a resource file.
Maybe this topic can be helpful to you:
[How to include version info from version.inc into the .rc file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821369/vc-2012-how-to-include-version-info-from-version-inc-maintained-separately)

Comment: Don't pay attention on .inc file. Focus on .rc file.
Do you use VisualStudio to develop?
This topic can be helpful :
[About Resource Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)